# How do I hide and unhide a DIV on my web page based on a checkbox check?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried this but it isn't working:

```
$('cbxShowNotifications').click(function()
{
    var tview = $('#treeview');

    if ($(this).checked)
    {
        tview.show();
    }
    else
    {
        tview.hide();
    }
});
```

EDIT -

Fixed a few things but I'm still unable to show the DIV AFTER I hide it:

```
$('#cbxShowNotifications').on('click', (function()
{
    var tview = $('#treeview');

    if ($(this).checked)
    {
        tview.show();
    }
    else
    {
        tview.hide();
    }
}));
```

Comment: You missed the `#` symbol for `cbxShowNotifications`

Comment: that helped me hide it. but if UNcheck, it is not showing the DIV on the page. do you know why?

Comment: check if `$("#treeview").toggle()` works (instead of the if...else block)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change ($(this).checked) to ($(this).is(':checked'))

Comment: Note that `.prop('checked')` is faster than `.is(':checked')` if only slightly.

Answer (score 1):

You have some syntax issues, and you should monitor the change event on checkboxes:

```
$('#cbxShowNotifications').on('change', function () {
    var tview = $('#treeview');
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        tview.show();
    } else {
        tview.hide();
    }
});
```

NOTE:  You can set the initial state by the trigger of the change event:

```
$('#cbxShowNotifications').trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$('#treeview').on({
    'change': function(){
        if ($('div').css('display') == 'block') {
            $('div').hide();
        } else {
            $('div').show();
        }
    }
})
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PWAwz/

Answer (score 0):

is this what you're searching? I wrote the codes below you can check they are working in example too. http://jsfiddle.net/jquerybyexample/xe7aL/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.checkbox1').change(function(){
         $('.tview').toggle('fast');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know your question is related to jQuery, but if the purpose is purely presentational, perhaps you can consider a CSS way to accomplish the same thing:

```
#treeview {
  display: none
}

#cbxShowNotifications:checked ~ #treeview {
  display: block
}
```

You can take a look at an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/BZQX4/5/